# How to make a golden isosceles triangle spiral/fractal, and its associated scaffold, with iterable depth?

Tags: geometry

[image: golden isosceles triangle spiral]

Any way to control the fractal depth while having both the spiral and the triangular scaffold as separate objects so that they can be manipulated together or separately.

I'm interested in this [exact shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_triangle_(mathematics)#Logarithmic_spiral).

Comment: Why/how do you want to manipulate the objects? I'm asking, because I've played around and it seems it doesn't work for other height to base ratios or at least the triangles stop satisfying the formulas for golden triangles in wikipedia.